Chrome extension service worker: abnormal delays with setTimeout() / setInterval()
Manifest: V3
I initially implemented a sleep function:
async sleep (ms: number) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
}

Problem: (only) when run from the service worker of my Chrome extension, the delay is random. Sometimes being very close to the ms parameter, sometimes VERY off (ex: ~5000ms instead of 500ms).
I know the timing is never guaranteed, but not only this issue only happens from the service worker (works fine from the content script or the chrome dev console), but also, this started to happen only a few weeks ago (~November/December 2024), while it was working fine for ~2 years before that, so adding that to the delay difference beeing that huge, I'm suspecting there's something else going on.
Then for testing purposes, I added the following code in the service worker, using setInterval() instead:
self.addEventListener('activate', () => {
  console.log('+++++++++++++ Service Worker activated')
})

var lastHeartbeat = Date.now()
setInterval(() => {
  const now = Date.now()
  console.log(`${now - lastHeartbeat}ms`)
  lastHeartbeat = now
}, 100);

I don't see any activations (besides the first time I start the Chrome extension) which rules out the possibility that the service worker gets idle/reactivated, but then the delays are just totally random, here's a random sample:
101ms, 99ms, 2055ms, 100ms, 3511ms, 394ms, 1416ms, 4439ms, 1341ms, 2862ms, 1216ms, 1794ms,
 1885ms, 802ms, 303ms, 405ms, 77ms, 100ms, 367ms, 34ms, 1348ms, 52ms, 99ms

Sometimes even reaching 10 seconds.
This seems to indicate that there's something blocking/delaying things in the event loop?
I thought of using chrome.alarms instead, but unfortunately this can only have precision to the minute in prod mode (or to the second in dev mode), not less, which doesn't work for me.
Maybe it's something that changed after a recent chrome update..
Any ideas?
The only other post that's vaguely similar is this one, but it unfortunately doesn't really address the problem, and is 6 years old.

Sounds like a bug in Chrome: it applies background timer throttling to an extension's background script.
